# Cakephp routing conflicts

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have conflict in my cakephp routes
The following are the routes

Here the second route is not working.Always goes to the first route.If if reverse the order, then also the first route is executing.

How can i solve this conflict.

Thanks..

```
 Router::connect('/:sluggroup/:slugsubgroup', array('controller' => 'groups', 
'action' => 'main'),array('pass' => array('sluggroup','slugsubgroup')));

 Router::connect('/:sluggroupevent/:action', array('controller' => 'groups',
'action' => 'addevent'),array(
'pass' => array('sluggroup')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it really causes a conflict because your routes are exactly the same which asks 2 paramaters. you can put another word to make it unique. or an action perhaps? like for example.

```
  Router::connect('{insert action here or unique word}/:sluggroup/:slugsubgroup', array('controller' => 'groups', 
  'action' => 'main'),array('pass' => array('sluggroup','slugsubgroup')));

  Router::connect('/:sluggroupevent/:action', array('controller' => 'groups',
 'action' => 'addevent'),array(
 'pass' => array('sluggroup')));
```

So in a url if you have a url -> /{unique word/action}/test/test it will go to route no. 1
if your url is /test/test it will go to route no.2

UPDATE:
base on you snippet:

```
  Router::connect('/:sluggroupevent/:action', array('controller' => 'groups',
 'action' => 'addevent'),array(
 'pass' => array('sluggroup'))); //you had only one params here in this line "/:sluggroupevent/:action" -> it seems that you maean to have two params or a type error.
```

Maybe you this will do it:

```
  Router::connect('/:sluggroupevent/addevent', array('controller' => 'groups',
 'action' => 'addevent'),array(
 'pass' => array('sluggroupevent'))); // it must be  sluggroupevent beacuse it is the once you have specified in   Router::connect('/:sluggroupevent/addevent', ..
```

Comment: if i use a unique word here it appears in the url too, but i dont wan't to show the unique word in the browser url.

Comment: Router::connect('/:sluggroupevent/:action', array('controller' => 'groups',
'action' => 'addevent'),array(
'pass' => array('sluggroup')));

In your snippet here, it looks like you are expecting two paramaeters, but you only specify one on your pass array?

Comment: i have an update for the answer. please clarify what youre routers are. like is it the :action a paramater? or you just mean it to be something like addevent?